# Azure Authentication returns to login page after successful login - node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, passport.js

I have a node.js appliation and uploaded it to Azure. I have included Active Directory support to the we application. Using Advanced option, I have set the client id and the required details to the application.

In Node.js application, I have used passport-azure-ad to authenticate the user.
I have configured the client Id, Secret, return url etc and I used the below get method to call azure authentication.

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/hello' }), function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/index.html'));
});
```

When I deploy the code and run it in azure, it first takes me to the azure login page and once I enter the correct email and password, it again redirects me to the login page. It didn't throws any error too..

Please help to avoid this circular process of redirecting to login page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you let me know how did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check what Url you have set `returnURL` in configuration and in Azure AD application's configuration. After you finishing authentication, it will return this endpoint.

E.G.

You set the `returnURL` to `http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return`,
You need to check the route `/auth/openid/return` like,

```
app.get('/auth/openid/return',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    log.info('We received a return from AzureAD.');
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

in your application. Whether it has redirect to login page, or it failed in authentication.

Comment: I have tried set the return url in Azure and application as '/auth/openid/return' and tried the above code.. But it result in same issue. Also tried with this return url '.auth/login/aad/callback'